# project have got interface ...i think this error by netbean

Tags: java, interface, inherited

I've got a project looking like this :

```
public interface Payable{
    double getPaymentAmount(); // calculate payment; no implementation
} // end interface Payable
```

then I've got an abstract class like this :

```
    public abstract class Employee implements Payable
    {
       private String firstName;
       private String lastName;
       private String socialSecurityNumber;
       // three-argument constructor
       public Employee( String first, String last, String ssn )
       {
           firstName = first;
           lastName = last;
           socialSecurityNumber = ssn;
       } // end three-argument Employee constructor
       // set first name
       public void setFirstName( String first )
       {
          firstName = first; // should validate
       } // end method setFirstName
       // return first name
       public String getFirstName()
       {
          return firstName;
       } // end method getFirstName
       // set last name
       public void setLastName( String last )
       {
          lastName = last; // should validate
       } // end method setLastName
       // return last name
       public String getLastName()
       {
          return lastName;
       } // end method getLastName
       // set social security number
       public void setSocialSecurityNumber( String ssn )
       {
          socialSecurityNumber = ssn; // should validate
       } // end method setSocialSecurityNumber
       // return social security number
       public String getSocialSecurityNumber()
       {
          return socialSecurityNumber;
       } // end method getSocialSecurityNumber
       // return String representation of Employee object
       @Override
       public String toString()
       {
          return String.format( "%s %s\nsocial security number: %s",
          getFirstName(), getLastName(), getSocialSecurityNumber() );
       } // end method toString
// Note: We do not implement Payable method getPaymentAmount here so
// this class must be declared abstract to avoid a compilation error.
    } // end abstract class Employee
`
```

and the last is a public class inherite Employee like this :

```
 *public class SalariedEmployee extends Employee*
```

and the hint error right here:
"error: SalariedEmployee is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPaymentAmount() in Payable public class SalariedEmployee extends Employee "

I don't know where this comes from. This code is taken from a book and should be perfectly fine. I'm using netbean 8.0 and jdk 1.7

Comment: `"i take from a book and i know it absolutely right"` -- until you've isolated the bug, don't assume anything. Odds are that the error is in your code. Trust me.

Comment: Also, please take the time to indent the code you post. The current code is *really* hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

You error code says it all. You have to implement every abstract method from your Interface `Playable`.
In this case you are missing the method `getPaymentAmount()` in your `SalariedEmployee` class.

EDIT: fixed class

Comment: Almost -- he has to implement that in his SalariedEmployee class, not Employee (unless he wants to) since it is abstract.

Answer (score 1):

You must implement `getPaymentAmount()` or in your abstract class (Employee) or in your `SalariedEmployee` because they implement `Payable` and this class contain the function `getPaymentAmount()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement each method as requested by the interface (`getPaymentAmount()`) and by the abstract class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed that proplem It just because i am not write all the code of this file he he .So basicly is when the time we write the line

```
public class SalariedEmployee extends Employee
```

the hint will appear only we write all the code and add method

```
public double getPaymentAmount()
{
return getWeeklySalary();
} // end method getPaymentAmount
```

to our program then the error will disappear .I've got it thank for support.
BTW code for file SalariedEmployee.java like this

```
public class SalariedEmployee extends Employee
{
private double weeklySalary;
// four-argument constructor
public SalariedEmployee( String first, String last, String ssn,double salary )
{
super( first, last, ssn ); // pass to Employee constructor
setWeeklySalary( salary ); // validate and store salary
} // end four-argument SalariedEmployee constructor
// set salary
public void setWeeklySalary( double salary )
{
if ( salary >= 0.0 ) weeklySalary = salary;
else
throw new IllegalArgumentException(
"Weekly salary must be >= 0.0" );
} // end method setWeeklySalary
// return salary
public double getWeeklySalary()
{
return weeklySalary;
} // end method getWeeklySalary

// calculate earnings; implement interface Payable method that was
// abstract in superclass Employee
@Override
public double getPaymentAmount()
{
return getWeeklySalary();
} // end method getPaymentAmount
@Override
public String toString()
{
return String.format( "salaried employee: %s\n%s: $%,.2f",
super.toString(), "weekly salary", getWeeklySalary() );
} // end method toString
} // end class SalariedEmployee
```